# Массив в React превращается в единицу

Tags: javascript, reactjs

есть форма, в которой два инпута, при изменении каждого из которых меняется state компонента `(recipeName, recipeIngredients)`. Дальше есть кнопка `Добавить`, которая создаёт объект

```
let recipe = {
  name: this.state.recipeName,
  ingredients: this.state.recipeIngredients.split(',')
}
```

и добавляет его в массив рецептов

```
addRecipe(e) {
        if (this.state.recipeName.length > 0 && this.state.recipeIngredients.length > 0) {
            let recipe = {
                name: this.state.recipeName,
                ingredients: this.state.recipeIngredients
            }
            this.setState({
                recipes: this.state.recipes.push(recipe)
            })
            this.handleClose(); //закрытие модального окна, в котором всё происходит
        } else {
            alert('Fill all inputs!')
        } 
    }
```

пытаюсь вывести содержимое массива

```
<ul>
  {this.state.recipes.map(item => <li>item.name</li>)}
</ul>
```

и на этом этапе массив `recipes` почему-то равен `1` и выводит ошибку `TypeError: this.state.recipes.map is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> this.setState({
>     recipes: this.state.recipes.push(recipe)
> })
> ```

`push` возвращает новую длину массива.

Comment: спасибо! проглядел в документации, что возвращает длину массива.